# Series and Sequences: Given $S_n = 3 n^2 - 11 n$, find $T_n$ and hence show that the series is arithmetic.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Q.**Given $S_n = 3 n^2 - 11 n$, find $T_n$ and hence show that the series is arithmetic.**

I have attempted to solve this question. Although no luck. Can someone pleas hint me on how to find the variable ($a$, $d$ and $n$)

Comment: What are did you mean with $T_n$ and $S_n$. Is $T_n$ a sequence and $S_n$ its sequence of partial sums?

Comment: What is a Tn???

Comment: yes Mario is correct.

Comment: Sn is the arithmetic sum. While Tn, is just to find the n'th term

Comment: Then $S_n = T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + \ldots+ T_{n-1} + T_n$ and $S_{n-1}= T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + \ldots + T_{n-1}$, so $T_n = S_n - S_{n-1}$

Comment: That dosent give much info on how to find the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S_n = T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + \ldots+ T_{n-1} + T_n$ and $S_{n-1}= T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + \ldots + T_{n-1}$, so

\begin{align}
T_n & = S_n - S_{n-1} \\
    & = 3n^2-11n-[3(n-1)^2-11(n-1)] \\
    & = 3[n^2-(n-1)^2]-11[n-(n-1)] \\
    & = 3(2n-1)-11(1) \\
    & = 6n -14
\end{align}

Note that $T_n-T_{n-1}=6n-14-[6(n-1)-14]=6$. Since the difference between consecutive terms is constant we conclude $\{T_n\}$ is an arithmetic sequence.